# Simple Output with Node.js and Knex.js Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have a small question today. I also found similar topics, which unfortunately did not help me.
I want to load data with Knex and use it further. In the first log `console.log(channel['name'])` in the then function I get the name as wanted, but in the last console log `console.log(channel);` I only get the message `Promise { <pending> }`.
What is the easiest way to use Node.js & Knex.js to get data in this way and use it further?

```
let channel = knex("channels").where({
    twitch_id: twitchID
}).first().then(function (channel) {
    if (channel) {
        console.log(channel['name'])
        return channel;
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

console.log(channel);
```

Comment: So from the first page nothing works. @jonrsharpe

Comment: You *must* move the `console.log` call inside the `then` callback, there's no way around that. You have to wait for the asynchronous result one way or another, it simply won't be available immediately.

Comment: But I need the data later. How can I wait for asynchronous? @Bergi

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? Put all the code that should run *later* (when the channel data has been loaded) inside the `then` callback - that's how promises work.

Comment: For example: I put let ´name = channel['name']´ in the ´then´ function, because need the name in the rest oft the script, but name is always ´undefined´ in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This package helped with my problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-mysql